# Invisible \[Conjugate] glyph in the linux frontend

Tags: front-end, bugs, fonts

**Bug introduced in 8.0 or earlier and fixed in 9.0.0**

*Concerns Linux*

---

I have a very annoying problem. 
The [Conjugate](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/character/Conjugate.html) glyph (*) does not show when I type.
That is, if I type `\[Conjugate]` or `⋮co⋮` then no character appears on the screen, although the conjugation operator is definitely there and working.

I'm running Mathematica 8 under Fedora. Here's a screenshot:

[image: annoying bug]

So far, it's the only character that I have noticed missing. Any ideas?

Comment: No such bug shows in Mathematica 8.0.4 on Win7. Can you try following this and let us know if it helped?

http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/2008/Feb/msg00035.html

Comment: I have the same problem as well; I'm running *Mathematica* 8.0.1 on Xubuntu 11.10 .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to make a backup and then modify the `UnicodeFontMapping.tr` file:

```
FileNameJoin[{$InstallationDirectory, "SystemFiles", "FrontEnd", 
              "TextResources", "UnicodeFontMapping.tr"}]
```

Look for the line

```
0xF3C8      N       6       0xad        # \[Conjugate]
```

and modify it to something like

```
0xF3C8      N       1       0x2a        # *
```

---

Thanks go to [ragfield](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/15/ragfield) for providing [this workaround on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5234668/421225).

---

**Aside:** In February 2011, I contacted [WRI tech support](http://www.wolfram.com/support/contact/email/) about two linux specific Mathematica 8 frontend bugs/regressions. The non-visible `\[Conjugate]` discussed above and the bad typesetting in fractions. Here's images showing the latter

[image: Frac in 7]
[image: Frac in 8]

The <s>helpful</s> tech support response was simply:

> These are known problems with the FrontEnd on Linux, which our developers
>   hope to address in a future release of Mathematica.

and that I'll be "notified when the issues are resolved"...

---

**Back to the aside:**
Both of the Linux front-end bugs mentioned in the previous aside have been fixed in the first version 9 release.